# System.InvalidOperationException: ServiceLocationProvider must be set in Prism ConfigureContainer()

Tags: wpf, prism, region

I'm new to Prism and following the tutorial Introduction to prism by Brian Lagunas, And I'm creating a custom regionAdapter like below.

```
public class StackPanelRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<StackPanel>
{
    public StackPanelRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehavior )
        :base(regionBehavior)
    {

    }
    protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, StackPanel regionTarget)
    {
        region.Views.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
           {
               if(e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
               {
                   foreach(FrameworkElement frameworkElement in e.NewItems)
                   {
                       regionTarget.Children.Add(frameworkElement);
                   }
               }
           };
    }

    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new AllActiveRegion();
    }
}
```

## In Bootstrapper

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
     RegionAdapterMappings regionAdapterMappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();

     regionAdapterMappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(StackPanel), 
            Container.Resolve<StackPanelRegionAdapter>());
}
```

I'm getting the exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: ServiceLocationProvider must be set

at here

```
RegionAdapterMappings regionAdapterMappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure your region adapter mappings in an override of `ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings`, not in an override of `ConfigureContainer` that masquerades as that.

```
protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
{
    var regionAdapterMappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
    regionAdapterMappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(StackPanel), ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<StackPanelRegionAdapter>());
    return regionAdapterMappings;
}
```

Hint: you get the exception, because `ConfigureContainer` is called before `ConfigureServiceLocator` and `base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings` uses `ServiceLocator.Current`.